# In XSLT Tokenize all values except those enclosed by quotation

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am trying to tokenize a line in XML that has comma separated values.
On which I used,

```
<xsl:variable name="lineField" select="tokenize(tag,',')" />
```

This works okay until I noticed that the amount values on 4th,5th,6th position were trimmed or tokenized which is wrong for my intention.

Below is an example line in the CSV file that has 6 values separated by 5 commas
Amounts are enclosed by quotes

```
, , Amount Paid,"133,654.70 ","9,356.10 ","124,298.60 "
```

`tokenize(tag,',')` results to 9 elements in the array instead of just 6

```
lineField[] = {'','','AmountPaid','133','654.70','9','356.10','124','298.60'};
```

**133** was split from "**133**,654.70"

**9** was split from "**9**,356.10"

**124** was split from "**124**,298.60"

which is wrong.

How can I tokenize all values in the line except those enclosed in quotes?
I can't seem to find a way.

I'd appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: I have some success using `analyze-string` with e.g. `analyze-string($s, '"([^"]+)"|([^,]+)')/*:match/*:group/normalize-space()` but it misses out on the first completely empty token and trying to adapt the `([^,]+)` to `([^,]*)` unfortunately fails the rules for the possible patterns allowed with the function.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Martin Honnen in comments, you will need to use `analyze-string` here to match the various fields.

After some trial and error, I came up with this

```
<xsl:template match="tag">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:analyze-string select="concat(., ',')" regex='(("[^"]*")|([^,"]*)),'>
      <xsl:matching-substring>
        <field>
          <xsl:value-of select="replace(regex-group(1), '&quot;', '')" />
        </field>
      </xsl:matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Or, using a variable....

```
<xsl:template match="tag">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:variable name="fields" select="analyze-string(concat(., ','), '((&quot;[^&quot;]*&quot;)|([^,&quot;]*)),')/*:match/*:group/replace(., '&quot;', '')"  />
    <xsl:for-each select="$fields">
      <field>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </field>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Note the regex group includes any quotation marks that delimit the fields, hence the use of `replace`. It assumes quotation marks are only used for delimiting fields with commas in and do not appear else, such as in the middle of a normal text field (If they do, you may be entering a world of pain....).